# What does the -0500 represent in this date? : 15 Jun 2012 23:02:10 -0500

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I was wondering how to format a date like this:

```
15 Jun 2012 23:02:10 -0500
```

and what the `-0500` represents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -0500 represents the number of hours away from UTC.  To learn more about GMT v.s UTC, see here:  http://geography.about.com/od/timeandtimezones/a/gmtutc.htm

Answer (score 5):

It is the timezone. That represents that you are 5 hours away from the GMT time. GMT -5.

Answer (score 2):

It represents the hour offset from Greenwich Mean Time.  This is the area where the standard date format puts the time zone information.